# Google Calendar does not set correct TimeZone

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, time-zone

I have an `ics` file that I'm importing to Google Calendar, and when I go to that Calendar Settings I read:

[image]

and I specified in `ics` file the TimeZone in use as:

```
TZID:Romance Standard Time
```

and in all events, as

```
DTSTART;TZID=Romance Standard Time:20101027T150000
```

problem is that, In all other calendars (Mac iCal, Mozilla Thunderbird, Outlook, etc) they all show the correct times, but in Google, I get all events +1 hour!

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [suggested fix available](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060423063554954) that might help but not sure of your exact circumstances. Basically, try resetting your Google Calendar timezone to something else, saving it and then changing it back to your correct timezone.